# Azure FrontDoor backend details addition on existing FrontDoor issues

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, url-routing, azure-front-door

I executed the following and was able to create FrontDoor rnd-test.

```
$test = New-AzFrontDoorBackendObject -Address bing.com -httpPort 80 -httpsPort 443 -Priority 1 -Weight 50 -BackendHostHeader bing.com -EnabledState Enabled

New-AzFrontDoorBackendPoolObject -Name "rndbackendpool" -FrontDoorName "rnd-test" -ResourceGroupName "Nexxe-RND-RahulTripathi" -Backend $test -HealthProbeSettingsName "rndHP" -LoadBalancingSettingsName "rndLB" -DefaultProfile $AzSubscription
```

Now, I'm trying to create a backendpool under existing FrontDoor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer to [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Update-existing-Azure-23a36fce) for updating the existing Azure Front Door new frontend, backend and rules.

```
$afd = Get-AzFrontDoor 

$bpoolname= Read-Host -Prompt "Enter name for backend Pool:"
$backobject1= Read-Host -Prompt "Enter name for backend object (IP address or FQDN):"
$frontdoorname= Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Azure Front door name"
$rgname = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Resource Group"
$routingRuleName = $bpoolname
$FrontendEndpointHostname = Read-Host -Prompt "enter FQDN of Frontend points name: "
$FrontendEndpointName = Read-Host -Prompt "enter name of Frontend point: "
$LbName = $bpoolname + "-lb01"
$probeName = $bpoolname + "-probe01"

$backEndObject1 = New-AzFrontDoorBackendObject -Address $backobject1



$HealthProbeSettingObject1 = New-AzFrontDoorHealthProbeSettingObject -Name $probeName -Protocol Https
$LoadBalancingSettingObject1 = New-AzFrontDoorLoadBalancingSettingObject -Name $LbName
$FrontendEndpointObject1 = New-AzFrontDoorFrontendEndpointObject -Name $FrontendEndpointName -HostName $FrontendEndpointHostname 

$BackendPoolObject1 = New-AzFrontDoorBackendPoolObject -Name $bpoolname -FrontDoorName $frontDoorName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Backend $backendObject1 -HealthProbeSettingsName $probeName -LoadBalancingSettingsName $LbName


$afd.HealthProbeSettings.Add($HealthProbeSettingObject1) 
$afd.LoadBalancingSettings.Add($LoadBalancingSettingObject1)
$afd.FrontendEndpoints.Add($FrontendEndpointObject1) 
$afd.BackendPools.Add($BackendPoolObject1) 



$RoutingRuleObject1 = New-AzFrontDoorRoutingRuleObject -Name $routingRuleName -FrontDoorName $frontDoorName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -FrontendEndpointName $FrontendEndpointName -BackendPoolName $bpoolname -ForwardingProtocol HttpsOnly 

$afd.RoutingRules.Add($RoutingRuleObject1)


Set-AzFrontDoor -Resourcegroupname $rgname -Name $frontdoorname -FrontendEndpoint $afd.FrontendEndpoints -BackendPool $afd.BackendPools -RoutingRule $afd.RoutingRules -LoadBalancingSetting $afd.LoadBalancingSettings -HealthProbeSetting $afd.HealthProbeSettings -Debug
```

Comment: Thanks @Nancy Xiong

Comment: Working fine for backendPool, but facing issue regarding RoutingRules

Comment: while defining "PATTERNS TO MATCH" like /path

Comment: Try to use `/path/*`?

Comment: "message": "RoutingRule gep-newBP with AcceptedProtocol Https FrontendEndpoint rnd-test.azurefd.net and PatternsToMatch /* conflicts with same or another RoutingRule that has the same AcceptedProtocol, FrontendEndpoint, and PatternsToMatch in the same Front Door; \nProperty 'FrontdoorEntity.FrontendEndpoints[1].Name' cannot be set to 'rnd-test.azurefd.net'. ; \nA resource reference was invalid: \"/subscriptions/bc8afca8-32ba-48ac-b418-77de827c2bc1/resourceGroups/Nexxe-RND-RahulTripathi/providers/Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/rnd-test/FrontendEndpoints/rnd-test.azurefd.net\""