# Azure Front Door bulk 301 redirect import

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-front-door

Is there any way to do a bulk 301 redirect import into Azure Front Door?
I tried finding a solution via PowerShell, reading some article but I got nothing.
Any OOB functionality of Azure Front Door like an import from csv or a powershell script?

Answer (score 0):

Powershell will be one of your best options.  Another option would be to download the Azure Resource Manager templates, modify them, and then reupload them.  You could even use [resources.azure.com](https://resources.azure.com) to modify the ARM template inside a web browser.  That will be the closest thing to OOB functionality with a UI.

Comment: Have you some suggestions on how I can start for the Powershell script?

Comment: Take a look at the New-AzFrontDoorRoutingRuleObject command here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.frontdoor/new-azfrontdoorroutingruleobject?view=azps-10.1.0  and also a general example here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61101640/azure-frontdoor-backend-details-addition-on-existing-frontdoor-issues?rq=3

Comment: If you have all your redirects in a format you can parse in Powershell, like JSON, you can include it in your script and iterate over each rewrite rule.